# SQL How to count by same date

Tags: sql, count

I have this SQL query:

```
select u.EMSUnitCallSign as Unit_number, 
   d.DestinationName,
   CONVERT(date, i.IncidentDate) as Incident_date, 
   COUNT(d.DestinationName) as Count_by_unit
from INC_Disposition d
left join INC_UnitInformation u on u.IncidentID = d.IncidentID
left join INC_Incident i on i.IncidentID = d.IncidentID
where (d.DestinationName like '%hospital%' or d.DestinationName like 
'%center%')
and i.PatientArrivedDestDate is not null
group by u.EMSUnitCallSign,  d.DestinationName, i.IncidentDate
order by u.EMSUnitCallSign, i.IncidentDate
```

It's current result show as:

```
A701    HospitalA 2015-04-15  1
A701    HospitalB 2015-04-15  1
A701    HospitalB 2015-04-15  1
A701    HospitalC 2015-04-16  1
A701    HospitalC 2015-04-16  1
A701    HospitalC 2015-04-16  1
A701    HospitalC 2015-04-16  1
A701    HospitalA 2015-04-16  1
```

How do I group the ones on the same date and count them together?

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the columns you select, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: Convert IncidentDate to date in the GROUP BY.

Comment: You have time in your dates. So the GROUP BY will split same-day, different-time into separate groups. You must do the same conversion you use in SELECT in your GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `IncidentDate` has a date component.  I am guessing that you are using SQL Server, and SQL Server doesn't allow the use of aliases in the `GROUP BY` clause.

So, the solution is to do the conversion in both places:

```
select u.EMSUnitCallSign as Unit_number, 
       d.DestinationName,
       CONVERT(date, i.IncidentDate) as Incident_date, 
       COUNT(d.DestinationName) as Count_by_unit
from INC_Disposition d left join
     INC_UnitInformation u
     on u.IncidentID = d.IncidentID left join
     INC_Incident i
     on i.IncidentID = d.IncidentID
where d.DestinationName like '%hospital%' or
      d.DestinationName like '%center%' and
      i.PatientArrivedDestDate is not null
group by u.EMSUnitCallSign, d.DestinationName, CONVERT(date, i.IncidentDate) 
order by u.EMSUnitCallSign, min(i.IncidentDate);
```

Based on your `where` conditions, I'm quite confident that you really want inner joins and not outer joins.